# How do get GIF from Google Docs using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to get the gif image from google docs. Using Apps Script, gif images are got as 
 InlineImage. But it's only static without animating.

My code

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl('url');    
Logger.log(doc.getBody().getImages()[0]);
var encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(doc.getBody().getImages()[0].getBlob().getBytes());
Logger.log(encoded);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the original images from Google Document.

  - In your case, you want to retrieve an animation GIF from Google Document.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

Unfortunately, it seems that the original images cannot be directly retrieved using `getImages()`. So in this answer, I use the method of documents.get in Google Docs API.

#### Flow:

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Retrieve the object from Google Document using the method of documents.get in Google Docs API.
2. Retrieve the source information from the retrieved object.

   - The embeded original images can be retrieved from the property of `inlineObjects`.
3. Create the original images from the retrieved source information.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

```
function myFunction() {
  var documentId = "###"; // Please set Google Document ID.

  // Retrieve the object from Google Document using the method of documents.get in Google Docs API.
  var obj = Docs.Documents.get(documentId);

  // Retrieve the source information from the retrieved object.
  var inlineObjects = Object.keys(obj.inlineObjects).reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    var o = obj.inlineObjects[e].inlineObjectProperties.embeddedObject;
    if (o.hasOwnProperty("imageProperties")) {
      var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(o.imageProperties.contentUri, {headers: {Authorization: "Baerer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}, muteHttpExceptions: true});
      if (res.getResponseCode() == 200) ar.push(res.getBlob().setName("image" + (i + 1)));
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // Create the original images from the retrieved source information.
  inlineObjects.forEach(function(blob) {
    var id = DriveApp.createFile(blob).getId();
    Logger.log(id)
  })
}
```

- When you run the script, the image files are created to the root folder. And you can see the file IDs of them at the log. The filename is "image1", "image2",,, as the sample.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [InlineObject](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/InlineObject)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: It's a great solution for me. The GIF images are got from Google Docs API correctly. What is the order sorted by images ?

Comment: @WeiYuan Thank you for replying. About `the order sorted by images`, if my understanding for it is correct, that is the order of `InlineObject`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/InlineObject) If I misunderstood your additional question, I apologize.

Comment: unfortunately the order of InlineObject is different from composition google doc. Is there good idea to align them ?

Comment: @WeiYuan Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your additional question. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information which includes a sample? By this, it will help users including me think of the issue and solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @WeiYuan There doesn't seem to be any way that I can tell (from inspecting the objects in the debugger) to map from the `InlineImage`s that `body.getImages()` returns to the `InlineObjects` used above.  I'm not sure there is any guarantee that they are in the same order, but if they are, there's our mapping...

Comment: @Tanaike If this script works as-is, maybe you don't need the authorization header, since `Bearer` is misspelled as `Baerer`, so I don't think it was having any effect.

Comment: (`InlineObjects` seems especially dodgy, since it's an object, and object key order isn't supposed to be guaranteed in general...)

Comment: @Kev Thank you for your comment and confirming it.